# Is it possible to get a summary of DONE and TODO's in Orgmode

Tags: org-mode

I am aware of the [0/2] checkbox summary in parent heading, but how could one get the same going for [(total TODO)/(total DONE)] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the `[/]` cookie in the upper level heading and then this will be updated with `[(total DONE)/(total TODO)]` each time you change the status of a subheading.  For example:

```
** My heading [2/4]
*** DONE bake cake
    CLOSED: [2015-05-17 Sun 13:24]
*** DONE make tea
    CLOSED: [2015-05-17 Sun 13:24]
*** TODO drink tea
*** TODO eat cake
```

If the cookie is not up-to-date, move the cursor to the cookie and type `C-c C-c` to update.

Comment: And if you use `C-u C-c C-c` it will update *all* the cookies at once.  It can also be useful to set the `COOKIE_DATA` property to `recursive` to count subtasks of subtasks.

Answer (score 2):

**Side comment** -- *If* you're exporting your task list to HTML, you might be interested by the dashboard of my theme Bigblow [1] (which I'll try to add into ReadTheOrg as well). There, you can easily see counts of items, and even highlight them.

See demo on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnSGSiXYuOk.

[1] https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes

Comment: Someday, for me, is in a very, very long time... ;-(

Comment: Took a look, very nice, no immediate use for me - I use org mode for README's on Github primary

Comment: 2 years later - took a look again, really useful this time around - thanks.
I also have been a huge fan of Leuven theme ;-)